# What is the criteria for extracting code into mongoose methods?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, coding-style

Let's say that I have a model called `User` which is self-explanatory. Our model has a field called `contacts` which holds a list of contact IDs. Now for adding a contact, one can use this express route:

```js
router.post("/contacts/add", async (request, response) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({
            sessionSecret: request.body.claimedSessionSecret,
        });
        if (!user) {
            return response.json({ result: false, error: "An error occured." });
        }
        let contact = await User.findOne({ email: request.body.email });
        if (!contact) {
            return response.json({ result: false, error: "User not found." });
        }
        user.contacts.push(contact._id);
        await user.save();
        return response.json({ result: true });
    } catch (e) {
        debug(e);
        response.json({ result: false, error: "An error occured." });
    }
});
```

The other choice will be extracting the meat of this route into a static method of our `User` model and then using that instead. Like this:

```js
// in routes
router.post("/contacts/add", async (request, response) => {
    try {
        const isContactAdded = await User.addContact(userID, contactID);
        return response.json({ result: true });
    } catch (e) {
        debug(e);
        response.json({ result: false, error: "An error occured." });
    }
)};

// in model
UserSchema.statics.addContact = async function(userID, contactID) {
...
};
```

Now the question is which approach is a better code design and why?

- Should I extract it into a User's method just because I am modifying the data or should that happen only if the statements are too many?
- Since we are able to use functions like `save()` and `findOne()` only after creating an instance of the model, shouldn't we be updating the DB the same way that I did above (first approach)? Because otherwise, we would have lots of `static` methods on our model.

Comment: It's called [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). This makes methods smaller and easier to understand. `addContact` only holds your application logic and doesn't concern itself with how to send back errors to a http client.

Comment: "*Should we do this everywhere*" - no. It's pointless to take this to the extreme. Do it only when you see a concrete benefit. Don't make functions reusable if you never need to use them elsewhere.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for SoC, I read it and I still have a hard time grabbing on the concept. Comparing the code above to when we create a new user of a model (use constructor and then call `save()`), the difference is that the user creation uses only functions of the model, but this code also changes the data. How is this a different "concern"? Should the user creation also be a static method and hence moved to model?

Comment: `User.create` already is a static method, no? You don't need a tiny wrapper function around `User.create(…).save()`. It only makes sense to separate this into a separate method if there's a benefit, such as avoiding code duplication, improving reusability (where necessary) and maintainability in general.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I seem to be realizing the error of my thinking procedure. I will be updating the question accordingly.